# Multiple OR operators TWIG (for a route)

Tags: symfony, twig

Hi everybody I was tryin to do something like this in TWIG

```
{% if app.request.get('_route') == 'route1' or 'route2' or 'route3' %}
```

How Can I do that? Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like this:

```
{% if app.request.get('_route') in ['route1', 'route2', 'route3'] %}
```

More: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#containment-operator